# Extract from array to integer

Tags: arrays, c, char, hex, unsigned-integer

How to extract the number 0145525000 from the array 0x00, 0x50, 0x52, 0x45, 0x01 in C language?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
   {
    uint8_t arr[] = {0x00, 0x50, 0x52, 0x45, 0x01};
    uint32_t number = 0;

    // Sorry i dont know how to solve this

    printf("Number: %d\n", number);

    return 0;
   }
```

It is necessary to convert from the last element to zero into one unsigned integer?

Comment: How is this array even related to the number you want to get?

Comment: One problem is that the array is 5 bytes, and an `uint32_t` is only 4. When they are the same size, you can use `memcpy` to copy bytes.

Comment: This sounds like it's a quiz or test question. If so, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1918561

Comment: In such a non-standard format, data from Icom devices are issued. Four right bytes will be enough for me

Comment: I'm a radio amateur, not a professional programmer, I need to solve a problem that I can't handle alone. Thank you!

Comment: You can do it the same way you would make 1234 from the digits 1, 2, 3, and 4: Multiply 1 by 10. Add 2. Multiply by 10. Add 3. Multiply by 10. Add 4. So, for your problem, multiply 0x01 by 0x100. Add 0x45. Multiply by 0x100. Add 0x52. Multiply by 0x100. Add 0x50. If you just want those four bytes, making 0x1455250, stop there. If you want five bytes, you need to use something other than a `uint32_t` for the result.

Comment: Quite likely, your problem would be better posed if you explained the context. Where are these bytes coming from? Some stream of bytes from an I/O device? How did they get into `arr`? Did they come one-by-one? Which one was first? Why did you put them into `arr` in that order? Why are there five of them?

Comment: This looks liken an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: If you know there are 5 and only 5 elements, you can do it concisely and efficiently with something like uint64_t number = ((((((((uint64_t)arr[4] << 8) + arr[3]) << 8) + arr[2]) << 8) + arr[1]) << 8) + arr[0];

Comment: This is format my incomming data 0xFE 0xFE 0x60 0xE0 0x03 (DATA AREA 5 BYTE ) 0xFD.  Data area 0x00 0x50 0x52 0x45 0x01 . This is format data for transceiver Icom-910H.

Comment: @СергейТ please [edit] your question and put all relevant information into the question. Also read this: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

The hexadecimal constant `0145525000` that will be more correctly to write like `0x0145525000` contains at least `9` hexadecimal digits (if to ignore the leading `0`) that can not be represented in an object of the type `uint32_t`. The variable `number` should be declared as having type `uint64_t`.

Now what you need is to write a loop that will store hexadecimal values present in the array `arr` in the reverse order to the variable `number`.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    uint8_t arr[] = { 0x00, 0x50, 0x52, 0x45, 0x01 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
    uint64_t number = 0;

    for (size_t i = N; i != 0; )
    {
        number = 0x100 * number + arr[--i];
    }

    printf( "%010" PRIx64 "\n", number );
}
```

The program output is

```
0145525000
```

The statement within the for loop

```
number = 0x100 * number + arr[--i];
```

may be rewriten also like

```
number = ( number << 8 ) + arr[--i];
```

Comment: @СергейТ No at all. You are welcome.:)